# Bluetooth doesn't work sometimes, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I am getting this strange problem with my laptop bluetooth not able to detect devices. Sometimes it works just fine and I can pair my headphones. During startup or shutdown sometimes I get this prompt

```
bluetooth : hci0 0cxxxxxx timeout
```

Here is the output of

```
:~$ uname -a; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware; lsmod | grep bluetooth
    Linux sayandeep-Lap 4.4.0-93-generic #116-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 21:17:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
    07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Unex DHXA-225 [105b:e044]
        Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    --
    09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
        Subsystem: Sony Corporation RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [104d:90ab]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b32f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e036 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    [    1.599868] usb 1-1.2: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
    [   12.889086] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
    [   12.889102] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
    [   12.889105] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
    [   12.889107] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
    [   12.889112] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
    [   15.218315] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1009 tx timeout
    [   24.399377] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
    [   24.399380] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
    [   24.399383] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
    bluetooth             520192  11 bnep,ath3k,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,btintel
```

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.